# LogbackMDCAdapter cannot be cast to itself

Tags: java, logging, jasper-reports, logback, classcastexception

I have to modify and re-compile a jrxml.
I use the JasperSoft plugin for Eclipse but when i try to open the report source code eclipse gives me this error:

java.lang.ClassCastException: ch.qos.logback.classic.util.LogbackMDCAdapter cannot be cast to ch.qos.logback.classic.util.LogbackMDCAdapter

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: ch.qos.logback.classic.util.LogbackMDCAdapter cannot be cast to
```

> ch.qos.logback.classic.util.LogbackMDCAdapter
>         at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggingEvent.(LoggingEvent.java:133)
>         at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend(Logger.java:471)
>         at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus(Logger.java:427)
>         at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.log(Logger.java:846)
>         at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.debug(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:133)
>         at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlDigesterFactory.createParser(JRXmlDigesterFactory.java:1591)
>         at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlDigesterFactory.createDigester(JRXmlDigesterFactory.java:1564)
>         at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.AbstractJRXMLEditor.doInitModel(AbstractJRXMLEditor.java:295)
>         at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.AbstractJRXMLEditor.init(AbstractJRXMLEditor.java:248)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.initialize(EditorReference.java:361)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:319)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:898)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:879)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:121)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:345)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:264)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:104)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:73)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:55)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:129)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:971)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:640)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:746)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:717)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:711)
>         at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:695)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$1.handleEvent(PartServiceImpl.java:99)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:40)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:186)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:145)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4761)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:211)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:36)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
>         at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>         at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:85)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:59)
>         at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:171)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:572)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:536)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:724)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:396)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1166)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3252)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$25(WorkbenchPage.java:3167)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3149)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3144)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3108)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3098)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:541)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:500)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:360)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:167)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:268)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:233)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(SelectionDispatchAction.java:275)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run(SelectionDispatchAction.java:251)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.navigator.OpenAndExpand.run(OpenAndExpand.java:50)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.actions.RetargetAction.run(RetargetAction.java:229)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonNavigatorManager$2.open(CommonNavigatorManager.java:191)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:48)
>         at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:854)
>         at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
>         at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
>         at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:851)
>         at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1168)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.handleOpen(CommonViewer.java:449)
>         at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$6.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1275)
>         at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:278)
>         at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:272)
>         at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:313)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
>         at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:694)
>         at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:606)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>         at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
>         at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
>         at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
>         at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)

Eclipse finds some error in the source code (but the error doesn't actually exist!) and I'm unable to compile the Jasper.

I have already reinstalled Eclipse, reimported the JavaEE Project and reinstalled also the JasperSoft Plugin.

Comment: could you add the line which causes this error?

Comment: It's not a line, this is the problem. The Jasper source is correct, but when I try to open or save it I get the popup with the error.